# Get statistical properties of a list of values stored in JSON with Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-zeppelin

I have my data stored in a JSON format using the following structure:

```
{"generationId":1,"values":[-36.0431,-35.913,...,36.0951]}
```

I want to get the distribution of the spacing (differences between the consecutive numbers) between the values averaged over the files (generationIds).

The first lines in my zepplein notebook are:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
val warehouseLocation = "/user/hive/warehouse"
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
val jsonData = spark.read.json("/user/hive/warehouse/results/*.json")
jsonData.createOrReplaceTempView("results")
```

I just now realized however, that this was not a good idea. The data in the above JSON now looks like this:

```
val gen_1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM eig where generationId = 1")
gen_1.show()
+------------+--------------------+
|generationId|              values|
+------------+--------------------+
|           1|[-36.0431, -35.91...|
+------------+--------------------+
```

All the values are in the same field.

Do you have any idea how to approach this issue in a different way? It does not necessarily have to be Hive. Any Spark related solution is OK.

The number of values can be ~10000, and later. I would like to plot this distribution together with an already known function (simulation vs theory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This recursive function, which is not terribly elegant and certainly not battle-tested, can calculate the differences (assuming an even-sized collection):

```
def differences(l: Seq[Double]): Seq[Double] = {
    if (l.size < 2) {
      Seq.empty[Double]
    } else {
      val values = l.take(2)
      Seq(Math.abs(values.head - values(1))) ++ differences(l.tail)
    }
}
```

Given such a function, you could apply it in Spark like this:

```
jsonData.map(r => (r.getLong(0), differences(r.getSeq[Double](1))))
```

Comment: This is cool, thanks for this tip, I already learnt something. Although I don't see, how can I go further, and get the distribution I want, as now the spacings can be extracted by taking row[2] - row[1], row[3] - row[2], etc..., which is not that convenient to do in SQL.

Comment: I'm not the SQL expert you are, so I would use the Scala REPL to come up with a function that takes a collection of values and returns a new collection with the differences between adjacent values. Then I would see how I could incorporate that logic into my `DataFrame` transformation in Spark. So basically a pure programmatic approach given my own experience.

Comment: Forget about `explode`. While helpful in most such scenarios, I have offered a potentially simpler solution.

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!